# Power off arduino via software

Tags: arduino, mosfet, relay

I have an arduino that is powered by a 9v block battery and enabled by a switch. I want to change the curcuit, so that when the switch is turned off the arduino remains powered until certain actions are finished, and then turn off.

However I dont just want the arduino to sleep, the power should be disconnected. This is important, because I have additional components draining power from the 5v pin (around 300mA) and I want those to shut down too.

My first idea was to use a relay in parallel to the switch. When the switch is turned on, the arduino turns the relay on too. When the switch is turned off, the arduino is still powered via the relay. The arduino detects when the switch is turned off (the switch is double pole, so i can detect its state with a digital input pin) and powers off the relay when the remaining actions are finished.

Is there a better way than using a relay? Can I use a mosfet or something  else instead of the relay?

And maybe, in the future, I will need the 9V for additional components, which should turn off too when the arduino decides to shut down. But when the relay/mosfet/..? is placed between battery and arduino VIN I can just connect those between relay/mosfet/..? and the arduino. So this should be simple.

**Edit:**
Based on Passerbys answer I came up with this:
[image]

The motor is just a placeholder for my additional components that drain power from the battery and should be shut down too.

Comment: A circuit schematic with your proposed idea would be helpful.

Comment: related: [Microcontroller soft off circuit](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/140416/7036),  [Momentary switch power](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/146493/7036)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A system I commonly use:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fShKZe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

M1 is normally held OFF by R1. SW1 pull M1 gate LOW when pressed switching M1 on. That then provides power to the Arduino.

The first operation the Arduino performs is to drive the GPIO connected to the gate of M2 (which must be a "logic level" FET with a threshold low enough to drive directly with an Arduino - you could also use an NPN BJT). That then bypasses switch SW1 keeping the system powered up.

The switch can then be released and the power stays on.

The Arduino can then release the GPIO by either driving it LOW or setting it to INPUT (R3 will pull it down in that case) switching off M2 which then allows R1 to pull up the gate of M1 switching it off.

The only down side to this circuit when working with an Arduino is you need to hold the power button in long enough for the bootloader to finish executing (about 2 seconds) before the power will stay on. It can be beneficial to add an LED (and associated current limiting resistor) to the GPIO that drives the gate of M2 so you get a visual feedback of "power on" (or you could use a separate GPIO if you so wished) so you know when you have held the button long enough.

Comment: A similar solution that solves the 'waiting for the bootloader' issue https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CnTguj_qvY

Comment: @ambitiose_sed_ineptum Not bad - makes it more complex to implement though (more components), and the 2-second thing actually acts as extreme debouncing of the button (the power on becomes a very very definite action that can't be accidental).

Comment: yup, just another suggestion in case the OP wants it. Say, wouldn't a pull up resistor (say 1k) from VIN to the gate of M2 accomplish almost the same thing?

Comment: Possible, though I wouldn't like to be linking VIN to a GPIO even through 1100Ω.

Comment: well, you could then control that signal with a npn bjt instead.

Comment: And then you're about as complex as the other circuit ;) There are many ways of skinning a cat, some messier than others :P Personally I don't suffer from the 2 second thing since I don't have a bootloader that waits like that. Mind, these days I rarely go for a complete power-off solution, but when you have the awfully inefficient Arduino I guess you need some way to limit the wasted power from the LDO space heater.

Comment: Thank you, this looks exactly what I need. The 2 seconds are not an issue for me. Can you explain why you use a second FET M2? I added a circuit to my question that only uses one, like Passerby proposed.

Comment: What would be good mosfets to use here? For M2 I need V_GS small (<2.5V with 5V Logic) and I want R_DS to be high, when the Mosfet is closed (so I have low power consumption when the device is off). For M1 I just need U_DS to be >9V. Is that correct? Anything else to watch out for?

Comment: For M2 you don't really care much about \$R_{DSon}\$ and \$R_{DSoff}\$ will always be very high. For M1 you want \$R_{DSon}\$ to be nice and low, and \$I_D\$ to be high enough to handle what current you need. Also you should watch power dissipation (\$P=I_D^2R_{DSon}\$).

Answer (score 0):

**A high side pnp transistor or p-channel mosfet** with a pull up resistor on its base/gate between the 5V regulator and your accessory circuit. When your arduino goes to sleep, set the control pin high or input mode to turn off the transistor. When you need the power, pull the pin low.

A relay is too big and will drain your 9V battery real quick.